# Best possible way to secure a OAuth protected web service call from iOS

Tags: ios, web-services, oauth

Currently building an app that will offer up some data based on location. This isn't considered very sensitive information, but I've been wondering what is the best possible way to protect the web service calls credentials in iOS, service is secured by OAuth. I know I could have a web-view and present the data that way, but really don't want to go that route.

Essentially I'm looking for the best possible way to protect the credentials of the web services that will be called from iOS which could be reverse engineered. Thinking of companies like Yelp, Foursquare, ect. How do you suppose they are providing data without requiring a login on iOS and keeping their web services secure?

Comment: No one wants to share their thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 2.0 relies on SSL for encryption between the client and server.

Comment: Thanks Ashish, I am aware of the SSL requirement and will be transfering all request over SSL already. My question is more about preventing reverse engineering of credentials in a OAuth Implicit flow. Or since this is a trusted app is there a secure way to store a client secret in iOS.